# Is there a way to change the target file format in kinesis firehose transformation lambda function?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, file-format, amazon-kinesis-firehose

We have a system like the one below.

[image]

We are receiving the data to lambda function in JSON format. It is clear that we can transform, filter and convert the source data. But, is it possible to change the file format to parquet in the lambda function?

We know that kinesis firehose itself provides the record format conversion feature. But, we have an ask to do that in the lambda function itself.

I have tried a couple of ways and was able to change the file data format. But, the file in s3 is still in a file format with GUID only in spite of the .parquet format.